# What does a surcharge for departure dates mean for an round the world ticket?

Tags: air-travel, around-the-world

I was looking for [around the world tickets](http://www.flightcentre.com.au/flights/product/Round+the+World-2154579) and I noticed the following text:

> Valid for departures 16 Jan 2012 - 3 Jun 2012 & 4 Oct 2012 - 2 Dec
>   2012. ADD $140* for departures 4 Jun 2012 - 3 Oct 2012 & 3 Dec 2012 - 15 Jan 2013.

Does that generally mean that you are charged $140 if your *first* flight is between the marked dates, or that you are charged $140 for each flight that is between the marked dates? Of course, I wouldn't buy anything without asking an official representative to clarify the situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just means that there are expensive departure dates because they're popular.  3 Dec to 15 Jan is the Christmas rush period as school ends and so on, while the June one is the other big holiday period.

It'll be based on your first flight, especially as out of Australia where you are, that's going to be one of the biggest.

(Just looked at the page, that's a pretty good rate for a RTW ticket!)